# MINUS operator in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have some tables where I am getting the emails. And I don't want to get the emails in table `tbl_unsubscribe`. I wrote the query like :

```
SELECT cand_email FROM tbl_cand_data
UNION
SELECT emp_email FROM tbl_emp_data
UNION
SELECT email FROM tbl_uptade_list
UNION
SELECT feed_email FROM tbl_feedback
UNION
SELECT admin_email FROM tbl_admin_emails
```

But I am getting a syntax error. Is the `MINUS` operator not valid for MySQL ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MINUS in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184592/minus-in-mysql)

Comment: Would like to point out the SQL in the question as it stands is valid in MySQL. There is also no "MINUS" in the SQL, but the question is about MINUS (which MySQL doesnt support as discussed below) which is rather confusing ...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A `NOT IN()` subquery can be used here, since MySQL doesn't support `MINUS`.

```
SELECT 
  cand_email
FROM tbl_cand_data 
WHERE can_email NOT IN (SELECT un_email FROM tbl_unsubscribe)
```

It can also be done with a `LEFT JOIN`, looking for NULLs in the `un_email` column:

```
SELECT cand_email 
FROM
   tbl_cand_data
   LEFT JOIN tbl_unsubscribe ON tbl_cand_data.can_email = tbl_unsubscribe.un_email
WHERE tbl_unsubscribe.un_email IS NULL
```

To exclude them from a bunch of `UNION` operations, wrap the `UNION` group in `()` as a subquery:

```
SELECT email FROM (
  SELECT cand_email AS email FROM tbl_cand_data
  UNION
  SELECT emp_email AS email FROM tbl_emp_data
  UNION
  SELECT email FROM AS email tbl_uptade_list
  UNION
  SELECT feed_email AS email FROM tbl_feedback
  UNION
  SELECT admin_email AS email FROM tbl_admin_emails
) email_list
WHERE email NOT IN (SELECT un_email FROM tbl_unsubscribe)
```

Comment: @AssamGuy See addition above.

Comment: It is showing `DB Error.
Unknown column 'email' in 'field list'
SELECT email FROM ( SELECT cand_email FROM tbl_cand_data UNION SELECT emp_email FROM tbl_emp_data UNION SELECT email FROM tbl_uptade_list UNION SELECT feed_email FROM tbl_feedback UNION SELECT admin_email FROM tbl_admin_emails ) email_list WHERE EMAIL NOT IN (SELECT un_email FROM tbl_unsubscribe) `

Comment: @AssamGuy Forgot the alias `AS email` in each UNION component. See change above.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately `MINUS` and `INTERSECT` are not supported by MySQL, but you can get the same result using `JOIN` for `MINUS`, `UNION` for `INTERSECT`.

```
SELECT cand_email FROM tbl_cand_data
LEFT JOIN tbl_unsubscribe ON (cand_email = un_email)
WHERE un_email IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you Darhazer. I will use it

Comment: +1 You finished the JOIN version before I finished adding it to mine.

Comment: This is a good solution. Using IN/NOT IN with a subquery is exceedingly slow due to a MySQL 5 bug (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417074/why-would-an-in-condition-be-slower-than-in-sql/3417190#3417190)