# How to find records are exist or not from table in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch records from first table & check that records are exist in second table or not:

```
tbl_user

userid      email
-------------------------
1       abc@gmail.com
2       abcd@gmail.com
3       abedd@yahoo.com
4       xyz@gmail.com
5       test@ymail.com

tbl_user_responce

id      responce_email
-------------------------
1       abc@gmail.com
2       abcd@gmail.com
3       abc@yahoo.com
4       xyz@gmail.com
5       abcd@ymail.com
```

### UPDATE

Note: In my secord table email is stored in xml format like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
<userinfo>
<email>stevemartin148@gmail.com</email>
<status>1</status>
<description>Success</description>
</userinfo>
</user>
```

i want to fetch those records that are not exist in tbl_user_responce from tbl_user

So from above records i want result like

```
Email
-----
abedd@yahoo.com
test@ymail.com
```

Does anybody know how to manage that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MINUS oprator in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386280/minus-oprator-in-mysql)

Comment: no i want to fetch email from first table & match with second table & if records not matched then display listing of unmatched records

Comment: @SteveMartin It's stored as XML in a text field?

Comment: Yes in responce_email field of tbl_user_responce

Comment: I think you need to reconsider your schema. If you need to store xml, keep it, but add extra ``email`` column to ``tbl_user_responce`` table and index by it. Otherwise you will have performance issues very soon

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tbl_user
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                        SELECT  1
                        FROM    tbl_user_responce
                        WHEREN  tbl_user.email = tbl_user_responce.responce_email
                    )
```

Or even something like

```
SELECT  tbl_user.*
FROM    tbl_user LEFT JOIN
        tbl_user_responce ON    tbl_user.email = tbl_user_responce.responce_email
WHERE   tbl_user_responce.responce_email IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you're asking for won't use any indexes, but this would seem to do the job as long as there's only one email per "responce";

```
SELECT email 
FROM tbl_user
WHERE email NOT IN (
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(responce_email,'<email>', -1),
         '</email>',1) 
  FROM tbl_user_responce;    
)
```

From the "I'd do an SQLfiddle if it weren't down" dept.