# SQL Set Difference

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I do the following in SQL:

```
select distinct(territory_id) from main_territorypricing

"minus"

select distinct(territory_id) from main_territorypricing where store_url is not null
```

Basically, I want all `territory_id`s that are contained in the top line that are not contained in the second line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MINUS operator in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386280/minus-operator-in-mysql)

Comment: just remove the quotation marks surrounding minus

Comment: @Jayvee: won't help. MySQL doesn't support `MINUS` (or the standard equivalent operator `except`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, of course, sorry!, I was thinking oracle for some reason

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to do as you said:

```
select distinct territory_id 
from main_territorypricing
where territory_id not in (
    select territory_id from main_territorypricing where store_url is not null
    )
```

But based on the logic of what you have described, the easier solution is:

```
select territory_id 
    from main_territorypricing
    where store_url is null
```

This, is, provided that you have only these two fields (territory_id and store_url) and the rows are unique.

Otherwise, there is another tricky solution:

```
select territory_id 
from main_territorypricing
group by territory_id 
having (max(store_url) is null)
```

Comment: You don't need the inner `DISTINCT`.  Slows down the query for no gain.

Comment: Plus: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function

Comment: Thanx @TrippKinetics and a_horse_with_no_name. 
Fixed.

Comment: The first query works. However, the second query would not work. What that would give me is all the territories that have at least one NULL value. What I want is all the territories that do not have any NON-NULL values. The second query gives me 129 results instead of 13.

Comment: @David542, please check the third solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct(territory_id) from main_territorypricing
where
    territory_id in
      (select territory_id from main_territorypricing)
and territory_id not in 
    (select territory_id from main_territorypricing where store_url is not null)
```

Comment: I don't think this is the best way to answer this question, but it is a reasonable answer.  I don't think it should be downvoted.