# Compare Existence Of The Same Field A Based On Field Batch

Tags: mysql, sql

A table has fields

- code
- batch

I want to know what code(s) are in batch 1 but not in batch 2.
What is the best SQL statement for this?

Comment: Use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` with correlated subquery. Or use grouping and `HAVING` with conditional sums. Or 2 copies and `LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL`. *What is the best SQL statement for this?* Some of mentioned above, depends on a lot of table statistic parameters. Or even maybe some another...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple options as follows:

**Using NOT EXISTS:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.CODE FROM YOUR_TABLE T
 WHERE T.BATCH = 'BATCH1'
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YOUR_tABLE TT
                    WHERE TT.CODE = T.CODE 
                      AND TT.BATCH = 'BATCH2');
```

**Using LEFT JOIN:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT B1.CODE 
FROM YOUR_tABLE B1 LEFT JOIN YOUR_tABLE B2
  ON B1.CODE = B2.CODE AND B2.BATCH = 'BATCH2'
WHERE B1.BATCH = 'BATCH1' AND B2.CODE IS NULL;
```

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386280/minus-operator-in-mysql, MySQL does not support `MINUS` - has this changed in the meantime?

Comment: Ok, Got it. Updated the answer!!

Comment: I tested the left join as I'm comfortable using LEFT JOINS.  Thanks for the quick replies.